# Laravel - 5.8 explode not working for implode

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I did save computer field like `implode`.

A user cannot bid on a order more than once. If the user clicks on the order again, he should be prompted with a response page noting the user of having previously bid on the order.

[image: implode]

```
$order = Order::where('user_id',auth()->id())
    ->explode( 'computer', request('computer'));
```

I create multiple checkboxes and I stored `implode` computer

order.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="1" id="hp">
    <label for="hp">HP</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="2" id="dell">
    <label for="dell">DELL</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="3" id="asus">
    <label for="asus">ASUS</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="4" id="acer">
    <label for="acer">ACER</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="5" id="sony">
    <label for="sony">Sony</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="6" id="fujitsu">
    <label for="fujitsu">Fujitsu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="computer[]" value="other_barnds" id="other_barnds">
    <label for="other_barnds">Other</label>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
</form>
```

OrderController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'computer' => 'required'
    ]);

    $order = Order::where('user_id',auth()->id())
        ->where('computer', request('computer'))
        ->exists(); 

    $order = new Order($request->all());
    $order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $order->description = $request->description;
    $computer = implode(",", $request->computer);
    $order->computer = $computer;
    $order->save();

    if ($order) {
        alert()->error('Warning', 'You ordered already');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please  describe your question and also show some relevant codes. What are you trying to do to achieve that feature?

Comment: I updated my posts.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the type of the column `computer`? One thing you are missing  is csrf_token. So add `@csrf` and see if solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't work, because `computer` field is a string and `$request('computer')` is an array.

```
    $order = Order::where('user_id',auth()->id())
    ->where('computer', request('computer'))
    ->exists();
```

Also, as my comment above, you have to pass a `csrf_token` to submit the form. So use `@csrf` in your form tag.

Try below code, I have commented every step for better understanding.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
     {
      $this->validate(request(), [
            'computer' => 'required'
       ]);

 //Now fetch the user's computer record, it will give you a string.

   $users_computers = Order::where('user_id',auth()->id())->get('computer');

 //convert this string to array

   $users_computers = explode(',',$users_computers);

 //Now check if there is at least one order is common or exists 

 $common_orders = array_intersect($users_computers, $request['computer']);

 //throw error if any orders exists already

 if(count($common_orders)>0)
   {
      alert()->error('Warning', 'You ordered already');
      return redirect()->back();
      //To give which computers user have orders you can access $common_orders values.
      }

$order = new Order();
$order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$order->description = $request->description;
$computer = implode(",", $request->computer);
$order->computer = $computer;
$order->save();
return redirect()->back();//pass here a success message if you want
}
```

Use eloquent relationship to fetch and store a user's orders more conveniently.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a little problem , The user may choose one. it did not work.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2xmm.png

Comment: Delete all  the record from that table and try again, and see when you get "11" in your record.

Comment: I deleted all recoreds allready (before test) but I did not solve my problem.

Comment: When you get "11" in you table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195437/discussion-between-sujeet-agrahari-and-mahmoud-khosravi).